# Timeout opening Realm Object Server 2.0

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I've got a valid connection to Digital Ocean. I've also installed and have successfully started the ROS on that server. See pics below.

Just to be clear I am using the public IP address for the Digital Ocean server (blocked out in the pics)

Now I can't figure out why, when Realm Studio says I'm connected
 successfully - does it then timeout ? Appreciate anyone's help to get this resolved.

[image: Realm Object Server running on Digital Ocean]

[image: The error]

Comment: I would like to get a look at your setup - please drop me a mail on kraen.hansen@realm.io and let's arrange a call.

Comment: Thanks, will get back to you tonight syd time